# How to use AWS Appsync with RDS Mysql database or with mysql aroura serverless database for real time syncing

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm building an application that has Web(PHP-Laravel) as well as Android UI. I need real-time sync of data between both platforms. For that, I'm trying to use AWS Appsync but after reading the documentation I'm so much confused about which service I need to use. There are so many options for integration like AWS lambda, API Gateway. So which one is appropriate for my requirement? Secondly, I'm not able to figure out how to connect the RDS MySQL database with Appsync for real-time data. AWS documentation is so much confusing that I'm not able to get it. Kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the AppSync SDKs for Web (JS) and Android. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android If you need to access realtime updates from PHP, you'll be out of luck, though. AppSync doesn't provide any PHP client for realtime updates.